# Energy of a system of particles in a reference frame

Tags: energy-conservation, reference-frames

When we have a system of particles, consisting of n particles, each having different mass and moving with a different velocity, we calculate the kinetic energy of the system in an inertial reference frame as K. When the same system of particles is viewed in frame moving with a velocity V, obviously the velocity of the particles change with respect to the frame and we thus calculate the kinetic energy as K'. We can see that K is not equal to K'.

Well my question was that how does the energy of the system of particles change when we simply view it with respect to a different frame of reference?

Answer (score 0):

Let us have a fixed reference frame (say we call it $XYZ$), and let the position of the $i$-th particle in this frame be $\mathbf{r}_i$. Let us have another frame (say $xyz$), whose origin is at a position $\mathbf{R}$ with respect to the origin of $XYZ$, and let the position of the $i$-th particle in this frame be $\mathbf{x}_i$. The frame $xyz$ is moving with a velocity $\dot{\mathbf{R}}$.

(I am going to define quite a few clumsy notations here.)

We have $\mathbf{r}_i=\mathbf{R}+\mathbf{x}_i$. We can write the kinetic energy in the $XYZ$ frame as
$$T_{XYZ}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_im_i\mathbf{v}_i\cdot\mathbf{v}_i$$
where $\mathbf{v}_i=\dot{\mathbf{r}}_i$. If we define $\bar{\mathbf{v}}_i=\dot{\mathbf{x}}_i$, then we can write,
$$T_{XYZ}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_im_i\left(\dot{\mathbf{R}}+\bar{\mathbf{v}}_i\right)\cdot\left(\dot{\mathbf{R}}+\bar{\mathbf{v}}_i\right)$$
When you expand this out, you will get,
$$T_{XYZ}=T_{xyz}+\frac{1}{2}M\dot{\mathbf{R}}^2+M\dot{\mathbf{x}}_c\cdot\dot{\mathbf{R}}$$
where $M=\sum m_i$. The **second term** on the RHS is the kinetic energy of the entire system which has now got the net extra velocity $\dot{\mathbf{R}}$. The **third term** basically comes because the center of mass may be moving, in general, in the $xyz$ frame. If $xyz$ happens to be CoM frame, then $\dot{\mathbf{x}}_c=0$, and this term vanishes.